# how can i send data via gmail but so that it cannot be changed

Tags: android, email

as I understand it, it is impossible to send without using gmail or another similar application, but you can change the message text in them, but I don’t need it

Comment: physically send a usb drive with the data on it?

Comment: Make a call to your Web service, which send the email on your behalf. If you want to use the *user's* email, then the *user* needs to have a right to inspect, edit, and perhaps reject that message.